# Android application crashing with RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity, dident find class

Tags: java, android, runtimeexception

I am creating an android application and when ever i try to run it the application crashes immediately and i get the folowing error in the LogCat

```
02-08 23:36:55.846: E/AndroidRuntime(15192): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-08 23:36:55.846: E/AndroidRuntime(15192): Process: com.danielscode.cube, PID: 15192
02-08 23:36:55.846: E/AndroidRuntime(15192): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to     instantiate activity     ComponentInfo{com.danielscode.cube/com.danielscode.cube.CUBEMenuActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.danielscode.cube.CUBEMenuActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.danielscode.cube-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.danielscode.cube-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
02-08 23:36:55.846: E/AndroidRuntime(15192):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
02-08 23:36:55.846: E/AndroidRuntime(15192):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
02-08 23:36:55.846: E/AndroidRuntime(15192):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-08 23:36:55.846: E/AndroidRuntime(15192):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-08 23:36:55.846: E/AndroidRuntime(15192):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-08 23:36:55.846: E/AndroidRuntime(15192):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-08 23:36:55.846: E/AndroidRuntime(15192):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-08 23:36:55.846: E/AndroidRuntime(15192):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-08 23:36:55.846: E/AndroidRuntime(15192):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-08 23:36:55.846: E/AndroidRuntime(15192):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-08 23:36:55.846: E/AndroidRuntime(15192):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-08 23:36:55.846: E/AndroidRuntime(15192):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-08 23:36:55.846: E/AndroidRuntime(15192): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.danielscode.cube.CUBEMenuActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.danielscode.cube-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.danielscode.cube-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
02-08 23:36:55.846: E/AndroidRuntime(15192):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
02-08 23:36:55.846: E/AndroidRuntime(15192):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
02-08 23:36:55.846: E/AndroidRuntime(15192):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
02-08 23:36:55.846: E/AndroidRuntime(15192):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
02-08 23:36:55.846: E/AndroidRuntime(15192):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
02-08 23:36:55.846: E/AndroidRuntime(15192):    ... 11 more
```

My first thought was that i had spelled the class names in the manafest file but i have double and tripple checked thoughs and they are correct. The folowing is my manafest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.danielscode.cube"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="0.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/cubeicon1"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".CUBEMenuActivity">

            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".CUBEGameActivity"></activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Has anyone else had a similar problem? any help fixing this would be much appreciated.

Comment: change `.CUBEMenuActivity` to `com.danielscode.cube.CUBEMenuActivity`

Comment: Just tried that, still dosn't work

Comment: This should not make a difference. Writing the full package name is optional.

Comment: after change try clean your project and if you install on real device first uninstall and test again

Comment: i tried to clean my project and re install but still no luck. i do have multiple packages in my project but the ones that are causing the error are just in the default one

Comment: @DanielBraithwaite can you post your `CUBEMenuActivity` packagename ple

Comment: CUBEMenuActivity is in the (default package), this hasn't caused a problem with other android projects

Comment: move CUBEMenuActivity to com.danielscode.cube, clean your project and try. @DanielBraithwaite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your problem is that your class `CubeMenuActivity` is in a different package than 
`com.danielscode.cube`. If you see your manifest you have defined that package and not in your java class.

Remove the package from your `AndroidManifest.xml` or move your class to a package that meets the one declared in your manifest.